# Unix shell script errors

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Below script is to push file to remote location through sftp,i faced lot of issues to write below code.But still i am facing some issue,Please guid me to resolve the issues.It's not working with sh.it is only working with ksh.

```
#test script 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/bin/sh
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# sftp_file_uploads.sh 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
export REMOTE_SERVER_PROD='192.168.0.1'
export REMOTE_SERVER_FAILOVER='192.168.0.2'
export SFTP_PORT='0001'
export SOURCE_FUNCTIONAL_ID='testusr'
export SOURCE_FILE_DIRECTORY='/var/temp/files/'
export SOURCE_ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY='/var/temp/files/archive'
export DATE_FORMAT=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
export LOG_DIRECTORY='/var/temp/logs'
export DESTINATION_FILE_DIRECTORY='/dest'
export LOG_FILE='$LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log'
export SFTP_BATCH_FILE='/var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE'
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find if the files are available at the source directory.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
cd $SOURCE_FILE_DIRECTORY 
export FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTD=`ls -lrt TESTD$DATE_FORMAT.csv  | awk '/TESTD/{ f=$NF };END{ print f }'`
export FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTDF=`ls -lrt TESTDF$DATE_FORMAT.csv  | awk '/TESTDF/{ f=$NF };END{ print f }'`
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Try 2 times and Sleep for 5 mins if either of the files is not present
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
counter=0
flag_file_found_TESTD=0
flag_file_found_TESTDF=0
while [ $counter –lt 2 ]
do
#---------------------------
# Check TESTD file arrived
#---------------------------
if [ -z $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTD ] then
      echo “No TESTD file to transfer. Sleeping for 5 mins” >> $LOG_FILE
 sleep 300
else
 echo “TESTD file found to transfer.” >> $LOG_FILE
 flag_file_found_TESTD=1
fi
#---------------------------
# Check TESTDF file arrived
#---------------------------
if [ -z $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTDF ] then
      echo “No TESTDF file to transfer. Sleeping for 5 mins” >> $LOG_FILE
 sleep 300
else
 echo “TESTDF file found to transfer.” >> $LOG_FILE
flag_file_found_TESTDF =1
fi
if [[ flag_file_found_TESTD == 1 &&
      flag_file_found_TESTDF == 1 ]] then
 echo “Both files are found.” >> $LOG_FILE
 break
else

 echo “At least one of the files is not found. Retrying now.” >> $LOG_FILE
fi
counter=`expr $counter + 1`
done
if [[ flag_file_found_TESTD == 1 &&
      flag_file_found_TESTDF == 1 ]] then
 echo “Both files are found.”
 break
else
 if [ flag_file_found_TESTD == 0 ] then
    echo “test file is not found and two attempts completed. Cannot transfer the file for today.” >> $LOG_FILE
 fi

if [flag_file_found_TESTDF == 0 ] then
 echo “test1 file is not found and two attempts completed. Cannot transfer the file for today.” >> $LOG_FILE
 fi
fi
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create sftp script
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
rm -f $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
echo "lcd $SOURCE_FILE_DIRECTORY " > $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
echo "cd $DESTINATION_FILE_DIRECTORY " >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
if [ -z $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTD ] then
echo "put $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTD " >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
fi
if [ -z $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTDF ] then
echo "put $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTDF " >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
fi
echo "bye" >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Do sftp
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo " Before SFTP " >> $LOG_FILE
if [[ -z $ FILE_TO_UPLOAD && -z $ FILE_TO_UPLOAD1 ]] then
 echo “No files to transfer” >> $LOG_FILE
       mv $LOG_FILE $LOG_DIRECTORY
 exit 1
else 
echo “Attempting to connect to  Remote Server $REMOTE_SERVER_PROD” >> $LOG_FILE
/usr/bin/sftp –v -oPort=$SFTP_PORT -b $SFTP_BATCH_FILE $SOURCE_FUNCTIONAL_ID@$REMOTE_SERVER_PROD >> $LOG_FILE 2 >> $LOG_FILE
fi
result=$?
errorConnectToProd=0
if [ $result -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "SFTP completed successfully to Prod Remote Server" >> $LOG_FILE
else
    errorConnectToProd=1
   if [[ $result -eq 4 || $result -eq 5 ]]
  echo "FAILED to connect to Server. " >> $LOG_FILE

   else
 echo "FAILED to SFTP to  Remote Server. " >> $LOG_FILE
   fi
fi
if [ errorConnectToProd == 1 ] then
echo “Attempting to connect to FAILOVER Remote Server $REMOTE_SERVER_FAILOVER” >> $LOG_FILE
/usr/bin/sftp –v -oPort=$SFTP_PORT -b $SFTP_BATCH_FILE $SOURCE_FUNCTIONAL_ID@$REMOTE_SERVER_FAILOVER >> $LOG_FILE 2 >> $LOG_FILE
fi
result=$?
if [ $result -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "SFTP completed successfully to Failover Remote Server" >> $LOG_FILE
else
   echo "FAILED to SFTP to Failover Remote Server. " >> $LOG_FILE
   mv $LOG_FILE $LOG_DIRECTORY
   exit 1
   fi
fi
cd $SOURCE_FILE_DIRECTORY
mv $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTD $SOURCE_ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY
echo “Moved $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTD to archive direcotry.” >> $LOG_FILE
mv $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTDF $SOURCE_ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY
echo “Moved $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTDF to archive direcotry.” >> $LOG_FILE

rm -f $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
echo “Deleted the SFTP Batch file.” >> $LOG_FILE
echo “Upload completed.” >> $LOG_FILE
mv $LOG_FILE $LOG_DIRECTORY
exit 0
```

Getting below Errors:

```
test.ksh[41]: $LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log: cannot create

test.ksh[55]: $LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log: cannot create

test.ksh[56]: flag_file_found_TESTDF:  not found

test.ksh[65]: $LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log: cannot create

test.ksh[41]: $LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log: cannot create

test.ksh[55]: $LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log: cannot create

test.ksh[56]: flag_file_found_TESTNDF:  not found

test.ksh[65]: $LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log: cannot create

test.ksh[79]: [flag_file_found_TESTDF:  not found

rm: /var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE is a directory

test.ksh[89]: /var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE: cannot create

test.ksh[90]: /var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE: cannot create

test.ksh[97]: B:  not found

test.ksh[98]: B:  not found

test.ksh[99]: B:  not found

test.ksh[100]: B:  not found

test.ksh[101]: B:  not found

test.ksh[102]: B:  not found

test.ksh[106]: /var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE: cannot create

test.ksh[113]: $LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log: cannot create

test.ksh[114]: syntax error at line 114 : `FILE_TO_UPLOAD' unexpected
```

Regards,

Chai

Comment: Where is the value of `$LOG_DIRECTORY` assigned?

Comment: @ alestanis: I agree,But It covered all my scenarios like logging,archiving etc..

Comment: @ Cthulhu: Already variable present :export LOG_DIRECTORY='/var/temp/logs'

Comment: Shell scripts can be hard to debug, but your question doesn't provide us with much to go on. Do you know what line of your script is cause the trouble? Can you perform that operation by hand? I'm going to vote to close for now, but if you edit the question to be more complete and more readable, I believe it can be re-opened so do not dispair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
export LOG_FILE='$LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log'
```

It should use double quotes, so that the variables will be expanded:

```
export LOG_FILE="$LOG_DIRECTORY/test_$DATE_FORMAT.log"
```

Another error:

```
if [flag_file_found_TESTDF == 0 ] then
```

needs a space after `[`. `[` is a command (it's a synonym for `test`), and all commands are separated from their arguments by spaces.

The whole section labeled "Create sftp script" is failing because /var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE already exists and is a directory; `rm -f` won't delete a directory, you need to use `rm -rf`.

```
if [[ flag_file_found_TESTD == 1 &&
  flag_file_found_TESTDF == 1 ]] then
```

is missing the `$` before the variable names.

```
if [[ -z $ FILE_TO_UPLOAD && -z $ FILE_TO_UPLOAD1 ]] then
```

Get rid of the space after `$`.

UPDATE 2:

In all your `if` statements, you're missing the `;` (or newline) before `then`.

I'm not sure what's causing all the "B: not found" errors. But after you fix all the other errors, maybe it will go away or be easier to find.

Comment: :Thanks,What is the differenc if i use single quote.What about other issues.

Comment: See edits for most of the other issues. The error messages all have line numbers, it should be pretty obvious what the errors are.

Comment: See UPDATE 2 for an additional one. I think those `if` errors are screwing up lots of stuff.

Comment: /var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE is a not directory it is a file,it will store all sftp commans.I already fixed if statement issues.One more question,B: not found error came after fixing octal ascii code errors(single quote replaced with octal code).this issue fixed using dos2unix command and using vi editor removed octal characters and replaced with single quote.

Comment: Sounds like you may have been using an editor that was creating smart quotes instead of normal ASCII quotes. Always use a plain text editor (vi or emacs) for scripts, not a word processor.

Comment: /var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE is  not a directory it is a file to store sftp commands.these commnds used while doing actual sftp.

Comment: Maybe that's what it's _supposed_ to be, but the error message clearly says otherwise: `rm: /var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE is a directory`.

Comment: any fix for this Barmar?